# jQuery CORS with credentials only works in Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, credentials, cors, request-headers

I'm facing a problem with my ajax CORS request.
I got it to work in any other browser, but Firefox doesn't send the Authorization header.

Heres the according code

```
$.ajax(
{
  type: "GET",
  url: 'http://www.urlhere.com/file.php',
  crossDomain: true,
  xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
  headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic .....' },
  error: function(data,error,errormsg) {
    $('#serverTestLog').html('<h3><span style="color: red">' 
      + error + '</h3></span><p>'+errormsg+'</p>');
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#serverTestLog').html('<h3><span style="color: green">success</h3>');
    }
  });
```

The problem seems to be that Chrome is the only browser which actually sends the Authorization header with the request. If I try it with Firefox, it's asking me for username and password, and after that starts a new request with the header set correctly, but I want to do this without user interaction.

I also tried to replace replace

```
headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic .....' },
```

with

```
usename: 'username',
password: 'password',
```

but Chrome is still the only browser who sends the Authorization header in its request. This time Firefox ends the request with

> NetworkError: 401 Authorization Required" without asking for username and password.

Does anybody have an idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are sending the request `withCredentials`, a preflight request is made before the actual request. The preflight `OPTIONS` request does not include user credentials [per the CORS spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/cors/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#preflight-request).

That `OPTIONS` request is most likely responding with the 401, and Firefox is reporting it correctly.

There are open bugs with [Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=139566) and [WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92755) where the subsequent request after the preflight are sent anyways even if the `OPTIONS` request fails due to a 401.

Comment: I have a similar problem, my application is built using Angular 7. I am making an ajax call to a BPMS server which works fine in IE but I have a CORS error in Chrome. However when I copy the ajax url to the Chrome browser I have all the data. Can anyone help?